# System.NotSupportedException: Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, n-tier-architecture, interceptor

I'm working with Ninject 2.0.2
Ninject.Extensions.Interception
with DynamicProxy2
Castle.Core
Castle.DynamicProxy2

The injection worked fine. 
Then I inserted the wcf between controller and bl layers. 
For interaction between the layers I've used the 
Ninject.Extensions.Interception of Ian Davis. 
I've used the DynamicProxy2 for creating proxies with help of 
Castle.Core and Castle.DynamicProxy2. 
In my Bl layer in classes there are references to implementation Types 
in DAL Layer. 
The interceptor is working when I'm marking the attribute of [Inject] 
on any property existed in BL layer . 
It means that when I cut off my connections from BL to DAL it works 
but it's useless . 
So the question is how to preserve the option of addressing DAL even 
though I'm doing it through intercept method.

I've found only post that refers to the subject - 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/ninject-2-dependency-injection?utm_sourc...) 
but it doesn't explain how to deal with it. 
In every class I've already created a constructor and also put an 
[Inject] attribute above it.

Note: 
If I remove Inject from property of IMyClassDao , I'm getting the 
Injection but without the property - it stays dead. 
How can I revive it ? 
I've upgraded recently to Ninject 2.0.2  from 1.5 - can it related 
version issue ? 
Does anyone has a solution for it?

Kernel handling :

```
using Ninject; 
using Ninject.Modules; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System; 
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception; 
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language; 
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Request; 
private static IKernel createDefault() 
{ 
    IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new 
    ControllerToBLModule(),new NHibernateModule(), new BlToDalModule()); 
    _kernel.Intercept(doIntercept).With<ControllerToBlInterceptor>(); 
    return _kernel; 
}
```

in controller to bl:

```
public class ControllerToBLModule : NinjectModule 
{ 
    public override void Load() 
    { 
        Bind<IMyInterfaceBL>().To<MyClassBL>().InRequestScope(); 
    } 
}
```

in bl to dal :

```
public class BlToDalModule : NinjectModule 
{ 
    public override void Load() 
    { 
           Bind<IMyClassDao>().To<MyClassDaoImpl>().InRequestScope(); 

    } 
}
```

So the code in my Bl is something like this

```
public class MyClassBL: GlobalBL , IMyInterfaceBL 
{ 
    [Inject] 
    public MyClassBL() : base() { } 
    [Inject] 
    public IMyClassDao  _daoInstance{get;set;} 
    public virtual IList<MyObject> GetMyObject() 
    { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

and in DAL :

```
public class MyClassDaoImpl : GlobalDAOImpl, IMyClassDao 
{ 
    [Inject] 
    public MyClassDaoImpl() : base() { } 
    public virtual  IList<MyObject> GetMyObjectDao() 
    { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

the error I'm getting :
Execute
System.NotSupportedException: Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructorNoLock(MethodAtt ributes 
attributes)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttribute s 
attributes)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.CreateType(Type Builder 
type) in e:\horn.horn\ioc\castle.dynamicproxy\Working-2.2\src ....

Does anyone have any idea on how I can preserve the hierarchy of addressing the layers through Ninject during using the intercept method ?

Comment: Can you make this legible please? Then hopefully the next person that's looking at it might read it and attempt to answer it (I answer lots of ninject questions but there's only so much time in the day).

Comment: I pretty much explained the all situation , including all the components.  The point is that the   _kernel.Intercept(doIntercept).With<ControllerToBlInterceptor>();
doesn't work and gives me this mistake - Parent does not have a default constructor . Have you met this before? Why could it happen and what are the solutions ?